# Wrong header of joined dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have grouped/counted and joined two data frames on column 'Amzius' and got one data frame df_joined.
Now I try to use it in combo chart and have a problem: I found 2 headers instead of 3. I miss column 'Amzius' (key column).
Print shows strange things:

[image]

Response to command `df_joined.columns.values` Does not give column 'Amzius'. I see only two columns: 'Atlygis' and 'Kaina'.

Here is my code:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Amzius')['Atlygis'].mean()
df_grouped1 = df.groupby('Amzius')['Kaina'].mean()

df_joined = pd.concat([df_grouped, df_grouped1],axis = 1, join='inner')
print(df_joined)
print(df_joined.columns.values)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Amzius is the index.

Comment: `df_joined = df_joined.reset_index()`